# Flask SQL Alchemy question about one-to-many Relationship between 2 different models

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I am brand new to Flask, so apologize for the simplicity of this question. Here is my issue:

I have 2 models, in 2 different directories (Directory Layout image below):

```
**************#1**************
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    # Create a table in the db
    __tablename__ = 'User'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(64))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(64))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    created =  db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    subscription = db.relationship('Subscriptions', backref='owner')

    def __init__(self, email, username, password, firstname, lastname):
        self.email = email
        self.username = username
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self,password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash,password)
```

as well as:

```
**************#2**************
class Subscriptions(db.Model):

    # Create a table in the db
    __tablename__ = 'subscriptions'

    id = db.Column(db.String(32), primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))
    lastcrawled = db.Column(db.Date)
    lastcheckedby = db.Column(db.Integer)
    isActive = db.Column(db.Boolean, default = False)
    datecreated = db.Column(db.Date, default = datetime.date.today())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('User.id'))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = email
```

And I am trying to figure out how to access fields in the User Model when showing the description Data (Models are linked on User.id field)

```
**************#3**************
    <div class="container">
        <table class="w3-row-padding table table-striped">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <td>Subscription Name</td>
                    <td>description</td>
                    <td>lastcrawled</td>
                    <td>lastcheckedby</td>
                    <td>isActive</td>
                    <td>datecreated</td>
                    <td>Owner</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            {% for subscription in subscriptions  %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{subscription.name}}</td>
                <td>{{subscription.description}}</td>
                <td>{{subscription.lastcrawled}}</td>
                <td>{{subscription.lastcheckedby}}</td>
                <td>{{subscription.isActive}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
```

Below is a layout of my site with the model locates shown. I am getting the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapped instance expected for relationship comparison to object.   Classes, queries and other SQL elements are not accepted in this context; for comparison with a subquery, use Subscriptions.owner.has(**criteria).
```

[enter image description here][1]

Site layout is here. Thanks so much!!!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK0oG.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's just an issue with your foreignkey and that's why it is throwing off the mapping for subscriptions

```
# db.ForeignKey needs to be user.id not User.id
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

Comment: I don't think that;s it as I explicitely named my table User instead of allowing SQL alchemy to name it based on the model name.

I got this error:

Comment: ```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.subscription - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```